# Finding array position on standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

`SELECT 2 IN UNNEST([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]) AS contains_value;`

returns true, but how can we get the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the position of the array with `WITH OFFSET`, but you need to move the `UNNEST()` to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]) value with OFFSET n
WHERE value = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the With Offset as Gordon said. I was just a little slow on my typing to get the answer up.